# Fire trigger based on two entries in table

Tags: oracle, triggers, conditional-statements, apex

I would like to know if it is possible to check a table for two conditions in a trigger.
More precisely, I want to decide what to enter based on entries from two columns.

```
    create or replace TRIGGER AUDIT_TABLE1
      -- starts on every update or insert
      AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON table1
      FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
   
      v_user varchar2(30);
      v_userid USERS.UUID%TYPE;
    BEGIN
       v_user := SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION','APP_USER');
       select UUID into v_userid from USERS where lower(username)=lower(v_user);

     IF :NEW.COLUMN4 ='REQUESTED'  AND :NEW.COLUMN5='TEXT123' THEN
          
       INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE1
      (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3)
       VALUES
      (:NEW.COLUMN1, :NEW.COLUMN2, 'TEXT123');
      ELSIF :NEW.COLUMN4 ='REQUESTED' AND :NEW.COLUMN5='TEXT3265' THEN
       INSERT INTO AUDIT_TABLE1
      (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3)
       VALUES
      (:NEW.COLUMN1, :NEW.COLUMN2, 'TEXT52354');
END IF;
END;
```

I'll get no error when compiling this trigger but I as well get no entry in the AUDIT_TABLE1 table.

Answer (score 0):

The *principle* is OK, which means that you either didn't post what you really have (which might be the case, regarding column names), or you didn't insert what you should.

Sample tables:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE table1
  2  (
  3     column4   VARCHAR2 (20),
  4     column5   VARCHAR2 (20)
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE audit_table
  2  (
  3     column4   VARCHAR2 (20),
  4     column5   VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     column6   VARCHAR2 (20)
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER audit_table1
  2     -- starts on every update or insert
  3     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  4     ON table1
  5     FOR EACH ROW
  6  DECLARE
  7     v_user  VARCHAR2 (30);
  8  BEGIN
  9     v_user := SYS_CONTEXT ('APEX$SESSION', 'APP_USER');
 10
 11     IF     :new.column4 = 'REQUESTED'
 12        AND :new.column5 = 'TEXT123'
 13     THEN
 14        INSERT INTO audit_table (column4, column5, column6)
 15             VALUES (:new.column4, :new.column5, 'TEXT123');
 16     ELSIF     :new.column4 = 'REQUESTED'
 17           AND :new.column5 = 'TEXT3265'
 18     THEN
 19        INSERT INTO audit_table (column4, column5, column6)
 20             VALUES (:new.column4, :new.column5, 'TEXT52354');
 21     END IF;
 22  END;
 23  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

These values won't insert anything because none of IF conditions is met:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO table1
  2       VALUES ('x', 'y');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM audit_table;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

These values will insert a row into the audit table:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO table1
  2       VALUES ('REQUESTED', 'TEXT123');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT * FROM audit_table;

COLUMN4              COLUMN5              COLUMN6
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
REQUESTED            TEXT123              TEXT123

SQL>
```